# How to get write custom tables in new file from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, file, csv

I have writed a script to extract table from csv file and write a new csv file that contains this table. 
So I have this code below :

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open("C:\\OpenFace\\x64\\Release\\processed\\webcam_2019-04-22-1552.csv") as csvfile:
    ddf= pd.read_table(csvfile,sep=" ")
    first_letters = ['eye']
    headers = ddf.dtypes.index
    df= pd.read_table(csvfile,sep=" ",names=[name for name in headers if (name[0] in first_letters)])
    print(df)
```

I'm trying to get only columns names who start from eye , 
but i get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "getpoints.py", line 8, in <module>
df= pd.read_table(csvfile,sep=" ",names=[name for name in headers if 
(name[0] in first_letters)])
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 440, in _read
parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 787, in __init__
self._make_engine(self.engine)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1014, in _make_engine
self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1708, in __init__
self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 542, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

How to solve this? 
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

#Read the only the header, i.e column names and breaks the execution 
#as only the column names is to be fetched.

with open("C:/path/to/.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    columns = reader.next()
    break


columns = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith("eye"), columns))

df = pd.read_csv("C:/path/to/.csv", sep=" ", names=columns)
```

Comment: C:\OpenFace>python getpoints.py
  File "getpoints.py", line 10
    break
    ^
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

C:\OpenFace>python getpoints.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getpoints.py", line 9, in <module>
    columns = reader.next()
AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: also when i correct those errors , i didn't get the format that i want.                  https://i.imgur.com/ChnXupq.png